# Replace a column/row of a matrix under a condition by a random number

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement, pattern-matching

Lets say there is a matrix of the form:

```
matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

I want to replace the elements of the last column, if they are larger then zero, by the element itself plus `RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-1,0}]`

I did it this way:

```
matrix[[All,3]] /. x_ /; x >0 -> x+RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-1,0}]
```

Afterwards I swapped out the third column of the matrix by this new one.

The problem with this approach is that `RandomChoice` picks between `-1` and `0` once, and either adds `-1` to all the entries in the matrix or it adds a `0` to all the entries. But I want it to do the `RandomChoice` for every entry individually.

How is that possible?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing when I run your code. If I do this instead `Map[If[Last[#]>0,Last[#]+RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-1,0}],Last[#]]&,matrix]` then I don't get the same operation done to every element. Because there are only three items, sometimes all three do the same thing, but not always.

Comment: `If[#>0,#+RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-1,0}],#]&/@matrix[[All,3]]` More compact, closer to your code, still works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify `->` (`Rule`) to `:>` (`RuleDelayed`).

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
ReplaceAt[matrix, x_/;x>0 :> x+RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-1,0}],{All,3}]

(* {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} *)
```

```
ReplaceAt[matrix, x_/;x>0 :> x+RandomChoice[{0.3,0.7}->{-100,100}],{All,3}]

(* {{1, 2, 103}, {4, 5, 106}, {7, 8, -91}} *)
```

```
ReplaceAt[matrix, x_/;x>3 :> f[x],{All,3}]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, f[6]}, {7, 8, f[9]}} *)
```